# Making a JLabel become another JLabel

Tags: image, jlabel

So, here is my problem. I have a JPanel, with a JLabel on it, and what I want is once that JLabel is clicked, it should resize, (ideally it will change with it's scale, but for now I am using a constant value). I have returned the image, and I now that I am able to scale it, but I just cant manage to make the original JLabel become the newly sized one.

So this is what should happen ideally, e.getSource should become the newly increased in size JLabel.

I know I'm pretty close, I did a JOptionPane as a debug statement to see if I can increase the size, and I can.

Why cant ((JLabel)me.getSource = a;
where a is my new JLabel?

Anyways, here is my code:

Please help me out.

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        //GreetingCard.setBackground.findComponentAt(me.getX(), me.getY());
        //GreetingCard.setBackground.findComponentAt(me.getX(), me.getY)

      JLabel a= (JLabel) me.getSource();
      Icon icon = a.getIcon();

        int scale = 4;

        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
            scale*icon.getIconWidth(),
            scale*icon.getIconHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
            g.scale(scale,scale);
            icon.paintIcon(null,g,0,0);
            g.dispose();
            JLabel temp = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi));
            ((JLabel)me.getSource())= temp;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            null,
            new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)));

      System.out.println("The size of the image is" + b.getIconWidth());
      initiateEvent = me;
        me.consume();



}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the statement  `((JLabel)me.getSource())= temp;`? Expressions (such as `((JLabel)me.getSource())`) are not allowed on the left side of an =. You'll most likely need to get the parent of the event source, remove the existing label, and add the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me.getSource() returns a JLabel, it doesn´t return a variable you can assign a new value.

Probably the best way is not to create a new JLabel but just assign the new ImageIcon to the old JLabel.

((JLabel)me.getSource()).setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));

You also need to call label or panel updateUI() to force a "hard" repaint with resizing.